# Strange "symbolic boolean expression has no truth value" error - is it a bug in SymPy?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

**Consider the following code:**

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.units import *

x = symbols('x')
eq1 = Eq(10 * (5*kg - x), 5*kg)
eq2 = Eq(10, 5*kg / (5*kg - x))
```

Unless I am missing something obvious, `eq1` and `eq2` are mathematically identical.

However, solving `eq1` for `x` works fine, but solving `eq1` for `x` returns an error:

**Works properly:**

```
print(solve(eq1, x))
```

Prints:

```
[9*kg/2]
```

However,

**Strange error:**

```
print(solve(eq2, x))
```

Gives this error:

```
TypeError: symbolic boolean expression has no truth value.
```

Any ideas? I need stuff like `eq2` to work for the project that I am working on.

Comment: Just FYI if a SymPy function gives "symbolic boolean expression has no truth value" it is almost always a SymPy bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug in sympy 0.7.5 and below. If I use the latest version from git, it works fine:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.physics.units import *
>>> 
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> eq1 = Eq(10 * (5*kg - x), 5*kg)
>>> eq2 = Eq(10, 5*kg / (5*kg - x))
>>> solve(eq2)
[9*kg/2]
>>> solve(eq1)
[9*kg/2]
>>> solve(eq1, x)
[9*kg/2]
>>> solve(eq2, x)
[9*kg/2]
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.5-git'
```

With the currently released version, you can work around the issue by using `check=False`, or passing `kg` in addition to `x`:

```
>>> solve(eq2, x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 901, in solve
    solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1418, in _solve
    for den in dens)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 1418, in <genexpr>
    for den in dens)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 111, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("symbolic boolean expression has no truth value.")
TypeError: symbolic boolean expression has no truth value.
>>> solve(eq2, x, check=False)
[9*kg/2]
>>> solve(eq2, x, kg)
[9*kg/2]
```